# Clicking on input component inside MaterialUI MenuItem triggers onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I trying to build a dropdown component that allows the user to multiselect and change each item's quantity.

The MenuItem component looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that if I try to click on the buttons or the input itself, it triggers the onChange prop and selects the item.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Select component code:

```
<Select
    multiple={step.MULTI_ESCOLHA === "S"}
    value={selectValues}
    onChange={handleSelectChange}
    input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chip" />}
    renderValue={() => 
    (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
        {selectValues.map((value) => 
        (
            <Chip key={value.ID} label={value.LABEL} onDelete={handleSelectDelete} onMouseDown={(event) => { event.stopPropagation(); }}/>
        ))}
        </Box>
    )}
>
{step.selectOptions?.map((prod) => (
    <MenuItem
        key={prod.ID}
        value={prod}
    >
        <Checkbox checked={selectValues.indexOf(prod) > -1} />
        {prod.LABEL}
        <QuantityInput
            min={0}
            max={10}
        />
    </MenuItem>
))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have onChange={handleSelectChange} at your whole Select component. When you change anything, handleSelectChange() executes. Try to add the "isChecked"prop to your MenuItem inside the onChange={handleSelectChange} and some conditional logic based on the "isChecked"